# Tuning regularised Cox proportional hazards models in tidymodels

Tags: tidymodels

I am learning tidymodels and trying to compare its usage & results with that of the source engine, here glmnet.
I found useful examples for fitting lasso or CPH but not regularised CPH.
The main issue is that "proportional_hazards" function seems to have an unknown mode (see the error message in example below) during tuning. I am unsure if this is my misspecification or an outstanding area of development in tune/censored of tidymodels.

Using the example from glmnet vignette (as a toy example no data splitting is done):

```
library(glmnet)
library(survival)
library(tidymodels)
library(censored)
data("CoxExample")
# combine list y and x for tidymodels
df=as.data.frame(cbind(CoxExample[["y"]], CoxExample[["x"]]))

# prep
lasso_prep <-
  recipe(time+status ~., data=df) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors())  #all predictors are numeric; 

lasso_tune <- 
  proportional_hazards(penalty = tune(), mixture=1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet") %>% 
  set_mode("censored regression")

lasso_workflow <-
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(lasso_prep) %>% 
  add_model(lasso_tune)

# specify lasso models
set.seed(123)
cv_splits <- vfold_cv(df, v=10)  
lambda_grid <- grid_regular(penalty(), levels=50)

lasso_grid <- tune_grid(lasso_workflow,
                        resamples = cv_splits,
                        grid=lambda_grid)
```

When the tune_grid was run, the following error message occurred: Error in `check_metrics()`:
! Unknown `mode` for parsnip model.
(I thought the mode under proportional_hazards has a singular default "censored regression" (also specified in above code)

From https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/details_proportional_hazards_glmnet.html, the CPH model specification seems to also involve fitting:

```
fit(Surv(time, status==1)~., data=df)
```

I've toyed adding this fit function in various locations, all unsuccessfully.

I would appreciate anyone pointing me to the right direction on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed found an active area of development here! So yes, with the CRAN versions, this does not work yet. Good news is that you can do it with the development versions of various tidymodels packages. You'll need dev parsnip, censored, and tune. I'll attach your example below with slight modifications for that.

If you want to read more on survival analysis in the tidymodels framework, please check out the [corresponding category on tidymodels.org](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/#category=survival%20analysis). This currently covers performance metrics since they were the missing piece to enable tuning.

One thing we recommend generally for tidymodels which is particularly relevant for survival analysis: it's easiest to do any transformations of the response before jumping into the analysis and sending things into various parts of tidymodels. Here, this means turning the `time` and `status` column into a `Surv` object before specifying a recipe or workflow.

```r
# install dev versions (and pak, if necessary)
#install.packages("pak")
pak::pak(c("tidymodels/censored", "tidymodels/parsnip", "tidymodels/tune"))


library(tidymodels)
library(censored)
library(glmnet)


data("CoxExample")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(CoxExample[["y"]], CoxExample[["x"]])) %>% 
  # for easier handling of the response in recipe and workflow
  mutate(surv = Surv(time, status), .keep = "unused")

# prep
lasso_prep <-
  recipe(surv ~., data = df) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors())  #all predictors are numeric; 

lasso_tune <- 
  proportional_hazards(penalty = tune(), mixture = 1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet") %>% 
  set_mode("censored regression")

lasso_workflow <-
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(lasso_prep) %>% 
  add_model(lasso_tune)

# specify lasso models
set.seed(123)
cv_splits <- vfold_cv(df, v = 5) # reducing the number of folds just for speed of this example

lasso_res <- tune_grid(lasso_workflow,
                       resamples = cv_splits,
                       # this will make a grid of 5 penalty values
                       grid = 5, 
                       # this is needed for the performance metrics, see tidymodels.org for details
                       eval_time = 20) 
lasso_res
#> # Tuning results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   splits            id    .metrics         .notes          
#>   <list>            <chr> <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <split [800/200]> Fold1 <tibble [5 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 2 <split [800/200]> Fold2 <tibble [5 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 3 <split [800/200]> Fold3 <tibble [5 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 4 <split [800/200]> Fold4 <tibble [5 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 5 <split [800/200]> Fold5 <tibble [5 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!